# I Want to create a unique id in django model with customer-auto incremented number

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There are 2 models, customer model and ticket creation for a customer

class cust_M(models.Model):
customer = models.TextField(max_length=8)

---

class TKT(models.Model):
tkt_unique_id = models.ForeignKey(customer) + autoincremented

when ever we create a instance for the TKT i want to increment the number for the customer.
eg:
customer1 - 1
customer1 - 2
customer1 - 3

customer2 - 1
customer2 - 2
customer2 - 3
...
...

Comment: Where Did you defined that autoincrement?

Comment: That is what i want to know, how can i define that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement me in models.py and it will autoincrement

```
from django.db import models
class Order(models.Model):
auto_increment = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Iam looking for something:                                                                                
                                              B_Costumer = customer+'-'+auto_increment

Comment: for that you have to change template and call this auto increment model in that tamplate with label name `Coustmer{{ auto increment variable name}}` this is because django save data in sever not print